# Find differences between images using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have two images taken from different view-points (some centimeters forward or backward), and I would like to find if there are new objects in the second image.

[The first one is the reference image](http://jamaslab.altervista.org/reference.png),

[the second one is the anomaly, (I attached just some tape on the wall).](http://jamaslab.altervista.org/anomaly.png)

Up to now I'm doing the following things. Finding the homography between the two images, splitting the images in small squares that correspond to the same area.

Any suggestions on which operation can be robust enough to find these anomalies between the pictures?

Comment: Have you tried subtracting the first image from the second image, leaving the difference? Not sure if this will work well enough for your solution, as small changes in lighting between the images may also be picked up.

Comment: Yes I tried, but since the images are not taken exactly from the same position, this can't be done (especially when an homography is applied)

Comment: you need some kind of image registration. try feature matching (e.g. sift/surf) and warp the images according to the found perspective homography. If camera movement was small you could try a dense optical flow instead.

Comment: wait... you already know the homography between those images? use cv::warpPerspective to correct the camera movement! After that you can basically subtract images.